# Is fsck -N mounted file system dangerous

Tags: linux, fsck

I've read to never run fsck when the file system is mounted. What about running fsck -N to only identify but not repair the file system when mounted? Is that dangerous? Is fsck -N known to overload a system and slow it down?

Answer (score 5):

`fsck -N` only prints the list of filesystems that would be checked. `fsck` is a front-end to filesystem-specific programs such as `fsck.ext2`, `fsck.btrfs`, … The option `-N` tells `fsck` not to invoke those programs but to print the command line that it would use instead. `fsck` itself doesn't actually read those filesystems, so it doesn't matter whether the filesystems are mounted or not.

If you meant `fsck -n`, then the filesystem-specific programs are called and passed the `-n` option, which for most of them means “look but don't touch”. If the filesystem is mounted, `fsck` will usually find spurious errors, because a mounted filesystem tends to be in an inconsistent state as write operations are happening. It won't lock up your system, but it won't report anything useful either.

Comment: Do you happen to know why `-n` is not documented in [`man fsck`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/fsck.8.en)? Or am I just looking in the wrong places?...

Comment: @toraritte It's documented as “fs-specific-options”.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a mounted filesystem is in an inconsistent state. So if you were to run that, it would likely print a bunch of spurious and completely meaningless errors.

Really, if you need to check the filesystem, unmount it.

Comment: No, with the option `-N` (note the capital `N`), the filesystems are not even read.

Comment: Yes, that's what `-N` does. But it's clear from context that he _intends_ lowercase `-n`.